# Probability in picking a computer from a laboratory

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

In laboratory 1, there are 20 computers, of which 14 are Dell, 6 are HP. In laboratory 2, there are 20 Dell computers and 10 HP computers. A new laboratory is being formed, for which 9 computers from lab 1 are taken, and 6 computers from lab 2 into the new laboratory. From this new laboratory, we randomly select a computer. What is the probability that the chosen computer is a Dell computer?

**How I would solve this:**

Let $A$ denote the event that a Dell computer is chosen.
Let $M_i$ denote the event that the $i$-th laboratory is chosen.

$P(M_1) = 9/15$ because we pick $9$ computers from laboratory $1$.

$P(A\mid M_1) = 14/20$.

$P(M_2) = 6/15$ because we pick $6$ computers from laboratory $2$.

$P(A\mid M_2) = 20/30 = 2/3$.

$P(A) = P(M_1) \times P(A\mid M_1) + P(M_2) \times P(A\mid M_2) = 9/15 \times 14/20 + 6/15 \times 20/30 = 103/150$

Now, knowing how tricky probability tasks are, I am not quite confident this is correct. Can someone please go through my answer, and if wrong correct it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is good. You should verbalize why you're "not quite confident" to help improve your understanding. IE Do you know what you're doing, or are you blindly copying a similar question's solution setup?

Comment: @CalvinLin not copying, just this is how I would solve it. And most likely I do not know what I'm doing.

Comment: To help resolve "I do not know what I'm doing": 1) What technique / idea are you using here? 2) Why is this the right technique to use?

Comment: @CalvinLin this is the total probability theorem. When I say I don't know what I am doing, mean I'm not sure how to solve probability problems correctly, and how to check my solutions.

Comment: If there is a confusion, try doing it by finding expected number of Dell laptops and HP laptops in the new lab. Then find probability from there. It may make simpler to think and can be less confusing.